# how to get listbox row index and every word index in that row

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hello im trying to get index of a row in listbox and also indexes of every word in that row.

for example i have 2 rows

first row : George Bush President
second row: barack obama President

first row index:1(0 if null based)
first word index:1
second word index:2
third word index:3

how do i make that happen?

Comment: You could iterate over ```Listbox.Items``` and ```string.Split(" ")``` each line into words. Not sure, what your next intentions are for that index, maybe put it in a dictionary or List.

Comment: thank you for response, my intentions for word indexes are to acces those specific words for later use. for example compare textbox text to that specific word.